# How to log file names which were processed successfully

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a Spring Batch application where I am processing multiple `.txt` files in parallel. My simple job configuration looks like below:

```
@Value("file:input/*.txt")
private Resource[] inputResources;

@Bean("partitioner")
@StepScope
public Partitioner partitioner() {
    log.info("In Partitioner");
    MultiResourcePartitioner partitioner = new MultiResourcePartitioner();
    partitioner.setResources(inputResources);
    partitioner.partition(10);
    return partitioner;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
@Qualifier("nodeItemReader")
@DependsOn("partitioner")
public FlatFileItemReader<FolderNodePojo> NodeItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['fileName']}") String filename)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<FolderNodePojo>().name("NodeItemReader").delimited().delimiter("<##>")
            .names(new String[] { "id" }).fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<FolderNodePojo>() {
                {
                    setTargetType(FolderNodePojo.class);
                }
            }).linesToSkip(0).resource(new UrlResource(filename)).build();
}
```

There are thousands of `.txt` files having thousands of lines which are getting processed. Some files have corrupted data and the job fails. I need to generate and send a report about the file names having corrupted data.

What should I do to log the name of the files which were processed successfully for all their lines, or, if possible, if I can log the unsuccessful ones, that will help too? So that I can generate a report based on that and also when I start the job again, I can remove those successful ones from the `input` directory. Any pointers/solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As a strategy, you could do something like this:

- once a file is in progress (say, filename `"file1.txt"`), step 1 is to rename that file, so the filename reflects that it's in progress; for example: `"file1.txt.started"`
- when a file completes successfully, rename it to reflect that; for example: `"file1.txt.complete"`
- if an error is encountered, and the code has a chance to rename the file, rename it to something like `"file1.txt.error"`

What's nice about this is you allow the filesystem to act like database for you, capturing the state of everything.

Once your program is finished, you can just count up the totals by file extension:

- anything named `*.complete` is good, those are the obvious successful runs
- anything with `*.started` is broken, and specifically it means something went really wrong
- anything named `*.error` is broken, but your code had a chance to notice
- anything named `*.txt` was, for some reason, not picked up

Those last three scenarios – `*.started`, `*.error`, `*.txt` – are the ones to study further, understand what went wrong. If all goes well, you'll end up with `*.complete` only.